# Unity Collision Remove then Add back

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, triggers, collision-detection

I have objects that scroll across the screen and do so endlessly. 
I want to remove the object when touched (I got that part) SetActive/Destroy.
I am trying to add the objects back to the scene so they can be re-used.

How would I go about this?

```cs
if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin"){
        coinCount++;
        coins.text = coinCount.ToString();

        // Save Coins
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", coinCount);
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
```

The Code Above is in a -> `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D){}`

```cs
// Waits Seconds to put coins in correct spot
IEnumerator afterSeconds(GameObject x)
{
    //x.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);//5f

    //x.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `MonoBehavior.Invoke()` and set a class variable to the collider, but this would be messy if you have collisions occurring before the re-enabling step. Instead I would use a `Coroutine`.

```
if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin"){
        coinCount++;
        coins.text = coinCount.ToString();

        // Save Coins
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", coinCount);
        StartCoroutine(afterSeconds(col.gameObject)); //hide, delay, show  
    }
```

and then:

```
// Waits Seconds to put coins in correct spot
IEnumerator afterSeconds(GameObject x)
{
    x.SetActive(false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    x.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Now I realize how simple my mistake was forgetting the Coroutine

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking for is object pooling. This is a system which manages the instantiation of dynamic amounts of GameObjects, by *not* destroying and instantiating them, but instead making them invisible and reusable. If the pool is running out of needed objects (because too many are in use at once), it can instantiate additional objects as needed. Usually there are assets which do that, but I guess it can be coded on your own as well. Even the official Unity tutorials mentions that and classifies that as beginner level: [Object Pooling](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling).
What then happens is that you simply replace all Instantiate methods with your InstantiatePool methods.

So in case you don't want to explicitely make GameObjects respawn in fixed delays, but allow a manager script to handle the spawning as wanted, that may be what you are looking for.